# Why is Aristocrat font not working HTML CSS?

Tags: html, css

Other fonts are working but it seems that the font "Aristocrat" is not working for me. What should I do?

CSS:

HTML:

```css
p {
  Font-family: Aristocrat;
  Font-size: 30px;
  Color: green;
  Font-style:bold;    
}
    
#date_of_birth {
  Font-family: Courier New;
  Font-size: 25px;
  Color: red;
  Font-style:bold;
}
    
#home_address {
  Font-family: Arial;
  Font-size: 25px;
  Color: orange;
  Font-style:bold;
}
    
#school {
  Font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  Font-size: 25px;
  Color: indigo;
  Font-style:bold;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>All About Me</title>
<link href = "EspinoJW_Q3W1.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>All About Me</h1>
    <p>My Name</p>
    <p id = "date_of_birth">Date of Birth: ********</p>
    <p>Sex: Male</p>
    <p id = "home_address">Home Address: Not Allowed</p>
    <p>Email: j********@iloilonhs.edu.ph</p>
    <p id = "school">School: ********</p>    
    <p>School Address: ********</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to do an HTML CSS project for school. The other fonts seem to be working fine except for the aristocrat...what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other fonts are built in. But that font is not. You have to link that font family to your page. For example if I want font family YellowTail from google fonts for my page, I will have to import it by adding below code into . You need to do similarly.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yellowtail' rel='stylesheet'>
```

If my answer works, please check it as final answer and upvote it so other people with same problem will get help too. Cheers